# Pressing a wrong key sheds blue light on whole screen in iTerm

Tags: iterm

Pressing a key that doesn't do anything, sheds a blue light on the screen for a moment, and it's quite annoying.

For example, in iTerm, since pressing <kbd>Down Arrow Key</kbd> doesn't do anything, so it sheds blue light on the screen to let me know there is something with what I'm doing, but it's pretty annoying.

I use Vim for development, and time and again, I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to switch between different modes, and this thing annoys a lot. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Have a look at System Prefs > Accessibility > Audio. Do you have Flash Screen activated? [You can test to see if it looks the same with the test button on there]

Comment: No, it's deactivated form here, but it's pretty much the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure it it's still an option anywhere, but the Mac used to flash the screen if the system volume was turned to zero/muted.

Comment: Does the same flashing happen with `Terminal`?

Comment: @danielAzuelos Yes. Everywhere, including Teminal app.

Answer (score 1):

Still have no idea what's wrong with it, but searching on Google gave me the following command to execute, and it did the job:

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

Comment: Google sold you as popular as stupid a piece of advice.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Kindly explain if I had something wrong.

Comment: Is it OK after a restart of OSX?

Comment: Restarted my mac after that, and it is working OK. No issues.